# Two of three scripts based on bs4 not work, but theoretically should

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I prepared three little scripts, that theoretically the should do the same, but two not work properly. I'm not sure what could be wrong. I used PyCharm, and packages was installed inside projects, not globally with PIP.

**First script** don't give me any results, just "Process finished with exit code 0".

```
import requests
import bs4

text = "Python"
url = 'https://google.com/search?q=' + text
request_result = requests.get(url)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request_result.text, "html.parser")
heading_object = soup.find_all('h3')

for info in heading_object:
    print(info.getText())
```

**Second script** same as above, only "Process finished with exit code 0".

```
import requests
import bs4
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

result = 'Python'
query = quote_plus(result)
link = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={query}"

request_result = requests.get(link)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request_result.text, "html.parser")

for p in soup.find_all('h3'):
    print(p.text)
```

**Third script** work fine, I have result from Google search.

```
import requests
import bs4


url = "https://www.google.com/search"
params = {"q": "Python"}
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0"
}
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select("a:has(h3)"):
    print(a["href"])
```

Can someone explain me please, what is not ok with scripts, that not worked? I asking, because theoretically they should work (they based on tutorial). Maybe exist better way than above to scraping Google results?

Comment: `heading_object` returns an empty list, so you will not get anything back.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like stating the obvious, but the main difference between your scripts is specifying a browser's header. For instance, your first script with headers:

```
import requests
import bs4

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0"
}
text = "Python"
url = 'https://google.com/search?q=' + text
request_result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request_result.text, "html.parser")
heading_object = soup.find_all('h3')

for info in heading_object:
    print(info.getText())
```

Results:

```
Welcome to Python.org
Downloads
Python For Beginners
[...]
```

Headers are how the browser present itself when knocking on server's door: server can choose to accept, or deny the request.

Answer (score 0):

it wont work because `heading_object` is an empty list. There are basically no `h3` found.

so i changed to `h2` and then `h1` to show it works:

```
heading_object = soup.find_all('h1')
```

this is the code:

```py
import requests
import bs4

text = "Python"
url = 'https://google.com/search?q=' + text
request_result = requests.get(url)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request_result.text, "html.parser")
heading_object = soup.find_all('h1')
print(heading_object)

for info in heading_object:
    print(info.getText())
```

this is the result (with the code):

```
[<h1>Before you continue to Google</h1>]
Before you continue to Google
```